# Determine whether a section with class is visible or not, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

This is a variation of others topics, the idea is to assign a `.js-visible` to any element in the DOM, and only when it is visible assign to it a `.visible` class.

The tricky part is that as all of the elements are using the same class name `.js-visible` I need to assign the class `.visible` to only the visible element and ignore all the other DOM elements with the same class name. If it was visible and is not anymore then remove the class name `.visible`

```
<style>
    .visible {
       background: green;
    }
</style>

<div class="js-visible" style="height:800px">I am 1st</div>
<div class="js-visible" style="height:800px">I am 2nd</div>
<div class="js-visible" style="height:800px">I am 3rd</div>
<div class="js-visible" style="height:800px">I am 4th</div>
```

This is not working as desired

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        var hT = $('.js-visible').offset().top,
            hH = $('.js-visible').outerHeight(),
            wH = $(window).height(),
            wS = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (wS > (hT+hH-wH) && (hT > wS) && (wS+wH > hT+hH)){
            $('.js-visible').addClass('visible')
        } else {
            $('.js-visible').removeClass('visible')
        }
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, this function seems to work.
You need to check each element individually.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var wH = $(this).height(),
        wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    $('.js-visible').each(function() {
        var hT = $(this).offset().top,
            hH = $(this).outerHeight();
            
        if (wS >= (hT+hH-wH) && (hT >= wS) && (wS+wH >= hT+hH)){
                $(this).addClass('visible')
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('visible')
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
    .visible {
       background: green;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .visible {
       background: green;
    }
</style>

<div class="js-visible" style="height:200px">I am 1st</div>
<div class="js-visible" style="height:200px">I am 2nd</div>
<div class="js-visible" style="height:200px">I am 3rd</div>
<div class="js-visible" style="height:200px">I am 4th</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to post a demo of the solution for who needs the same solution, you can adapt to your project

```js
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
  $('.js-visible').each(function() {
  
      var activeColor = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
      $(this).addClass('visible');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('visible');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
    .visible {
       background: green;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-visible" style="height:800px">I am 1st</div>
<div class="js-visible" style="height:800px">I am 2nd</div>
<div class="" style="height:800px">I am something else</div>
<div class="" style="height:800px">I am something else</div>
<div class="js-visible" style="height:800px">I am 3rd</div>
<div class="js-visible" style="height:800px">I am 4th</div>
```